# Trigger function after upload

Tags: javascript, webix

I implemented an upload button into webix. The event `onBeforeFileAdd` will be triggered.

```
on: {
  onBeforeFileAdd: function(item){
    var type = item.type.toLowerCase();  // deriving file extension
    if (type != "csv"){  // checking the format
      webix.message("Only csv files are allowed.");
      return false;
    }
  },
  onUploadComplete: function(response) {
    webix.message("done");
  }
}
```

Either `onUploadComplete` or `onFileUpload` didn't work. I have also put `console.log` but it seems to be that these events will not be triggered. The upload url responses status code 200.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onUploadComplete` event will only fire if the response contains an object that looks like this:

```
{ status: 'server', sname:'some server name'};
```

Per [their documentation](http://docs.webix.com/api__ui.uploader_onuploadcomplete_event.html):

> echo "{ status: 'server', sname:'$sname'}";

Comment: Thank you! I saw this article. There is no explicit hint that you need this response structure to get the callback... so i just looked for status 200. :(

Comment: Is there any reason why it doesn't fire on status 200?

Comment: The only reason it doesn't fire is because that's how they coded their API, no other reason. You'd have to ask the authors.

Comment: Ok :) I just thought I've overseen some reason.